# importing data from .MYD back up file

Tags: sql, mysql

How I can load the data from myd back up file to the database table? I have all 3 files:
`frm` , `myd` and `myi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXAMPLE the MyISAM table you are restoring is called mytable and datadir is /var/lib/mysql

SHOW DATABASES;

If one of the databases is named 'sample'

Step 1) Drop the mytable.frm, mytable.MYD, and mytable.MYI files /var/lib/mysql/sample

Step 2) cd /var/lib/mysql/sample

Step 3) chown mysql:mysql mytable.*

THAT's IT !!!

There is nothing to worry about in terms of mysql GRANTS. The information_schema will automatically record the presence of the new table in its tables. No need to restart mysql whatsoever.

In mysql client,

```
use sample
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable\G
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='sample' AND table_name='mytable'\G
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mytable;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you just can [copy the files into your MySQL datadir](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html) and (re)start mysql - the database will be available for local use as "root".

As access permissions are not stored in the database itself, but in a table of the "mysql" database, you might need to add permissions for access by remote or non-root users [using the GRANT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html).